# XML/DOM - Can't update empty node value

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm having difficulty modifying values in an XML file, I have the below code snippet.
The XML snippet below is a very cut down version of the XML file, I keep getting this error when I run the code:

### Error

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in updateXML.php
```

### PHP

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($vNewFile);
$vPayment = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Payment");
foreach ($vPayment AS $vPaymt) {
    $vPaymt->Name->nodeValue = self::NAME;
}
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Customer>
        ...
        <Payment>
            <Name></Name>
            ...
        </Payment>
        ...
    </Customer>
</Document>
```

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated as I'm stupid, just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
$vPaymt->Name->nodeValue = self::NAME;
```

It is not related to DOM. Here is another source that reproduces the error message:

```
$o = new stdClass();
$o->PropertyName->SubPropertyName = 23;
```

Message:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /tmp/ex... on line 4
```

What happens is that `$vPaymt` is an object (a DOMElement), but `$vPaymt->Name` is a non existing property. You use that non existing property as an object by writing a property of it. PHP initializes it as a default object and warns you about that.

DOM has no autmatic mapping for child elements (like SimpleXML). You should use XPath to fetch the Name node.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Customer>
        <Payment>
            <Name></Name>
        </Payment>
    </Customer>
</Document>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//Payment/Name') as $node) {
  $node->nodeValue = '';
  $node->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('FOO'));
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <Customer>
        <Payment>
            <Name>FOO</Name>
        </Payment>
    </Customer>
</Document>
```

### WARNING!

Never write DOMNode::$nodeValue with a string from a variable. It does not fully escape the provided string. Setting an empty string is fine (no characters to escape). Always create a text node and append it to avoid broken XML.